# Writing "manually" a vector from a data in R

Tags: r, vector

I want to extract "letters"(numbers) from a data set and put it in R code to create a vector.
For example:

```
    # my data is the following:
    x = rep(1,100)
```

and i want the R to write following:

```
    s = c(1,1,1......,1,1)
```

There is a way to do that without tipping every vector's entry?

Thank you for the helping.

Comment: Are you looking for `dput(x)`?

Comment: I think that will work, but there is a faster way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "faster"? Why do you need this?

Comment: I mean faster if i dont have to copy and paste every variable i want, my data set is huge. I want to do that because i'm running in a pc cluster and my r data file is unable to open there.

Comment: So, i trying to manually create the data frame.

Comment: So, we have an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/203914) here. Focus on the actual problem instead: You want to transfer data from your local system to a PC cluster.

Comment: Yeah...but this is a question too, I know that R can do almost everything.

Comment: Well, you can `dput` a data.frame, but in the long run you would be served better with learning proper ways of data transfer.

Comment: Indeed, but I also have other problems in the cluster and I trying to run as soon as possible.